# Visual Studio 2008 Report Designer - can't turn on gridlines

Tags: visual-studio

Microsoft in their infinite wisdom have seen fit to remove the useful "Draw Grid" and "Snap to Grid" checkboxes in the report properties dialog that were in VS 2005 but are not in VS 2008. I'm assuming they put that functionality elsewhere but I can't find it after going through what seems like every menu option available. Does anybody know how to turn on the gridlines?

Answer (score 1):

right click menu

h ttp://i37.tinypic.com/2vijfck.jpg

report properties dialog

h ttp://i33.tinypic.com/2yvnhus.jpg

You absolutely sure you're using VS 2008? - looks like the 2005 dialog to me

Answer (score 1):

There´s no how to do it, microsoft just took it off, because now the objects align with other objects, and you have 3 options to move the objects now, with mouse, by selecting the object and moving with your **arrows** in keyboard, which moves around 0,30 cm, and by holding **ctrl** and pressing arrows, which is more precisely.

There´s a lot of people complaining about that, maybe they will put this functionality back, I don´t know....

Answer (score 0):

[alt text http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7299/vs2008snaptogrid.png](http://img16.imageshack.us/img16/7299/vs2008snaptogrid.png)
If you right click off to the right of your report  and select properties you will find Draw grid and Snap to Grid

Comment: I know that is the case in VS 2005, but it doesn't work in VS 2008. The report properties dialog that you access by right clicking in VS 2008 does not contain any grid options.

Comment: I am using VS 2008, the properties on the right hand side of the screen does not show the grid option but if you click inside the report widow off to the right of the report form itself it does. One other possibilty have you downloaded SP1?

Comment: Yes I'm using SP1. I'm right clicking just outside the report but still within the report window. In the menu I have:

View
-------
Add Page Header
Add Page Footer
-------
Report Properties

Doing the same in VS 2005:

Report Parameters
------
Page Header
Page Footer
------
Properties

Selecting "Report Properties" in the 2008 version brings up the report properties dialog with the Page Setup tab open as default. There are settings for Page Units, Paper Size and Margins but no grid options.

Comment: The equivilant operation in VS 2005 is selecting "Properties" which opens the report properties dialog with the "General" tab open as default, the grid settings are there below Author and Description.

According to this MS Connect article https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=357258 they've removed the grid functionality entirely in VS 2008 Report Designer and replaced it with object snapping and snap lines. Judging by the comments, people are finding this just as much of a PITA as I am

Comment: Sorry I don't understand why it's not there, I am using VS2008 Professional Edition Version 9.0.30729.1 SP and the grid options are there in C# and VB reports as you describe in VS2005

Comment: Can't understand it either, I appear to be using the exact same version as you 9.0.30729.1.

Comment: It looks like you are runnung it under Vista, I am using XP. I'll try it out on a Vista machine, and yes it is VS2008

Comment: My vista machine looks much the same and my xp machine